# Python Tkinter Save Listbox Item Ordering to Sqlite Database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a drag-and-drop listbox ([found here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch11s05.html)) that lets the user drag/move items up or down to re-order them.

I have a `db.sqlite` file that looks like this initially:

```
>>> make_df()
    ordering          fruit
0          0         apples
1          1        oranges
2          2    blueberries
3          3     watermelon
4          4     cantaloupe
5          5          pears
6          6    pomegranate
7          7    raspberries
8          8   blackberries
9          9  boysenberries
10        10     nectarines
```

What I am trying to do is reorder items around in the listbox and have that order saved to the database so when I re-launch the program, the items are in the same order as the last time I used it.

The problem:
Every time I relaunch the program, the items from the listbox are always in the same order. However, when I reorder the items, then run `make_df` which looks into the database to see the ordering and returns a dataframe, it shows the database during  that session did update.  **It's just not saving it permanently and that's what I can't figure out.**

[image: Example]

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
root = tk.Tk()

def make_sqlite_db_for_stackoverflow():
  connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
  db_file_name = 'db.sqlite'
  df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(0, 'apples'), (1, 'oranges'), (2, 'blueberries'), (3, 'watermelon'),
     (4, 'cantaloupe'), (5, 'pears'), (6, 'pomegranate'), (7, 'raspberries'),
     (8, 'blackberries'), (9, 'boysenberries'), (10, 'nectarines')],
    columns=['ordering', 'fruit']
    )
  df.to_sql('columns', connection, index=False, if_exists='replace')
  connection.close()

make_sqlite_db_for_stackoverflow()

def make_df():
  print(pd.DataFrame(sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite').cursor().execute(
    'SELECT * FROM columns ORDER BY "ordering";').fetchall(), columns=['ordering', 'fruit']))

class Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(tk.Listbox):
  """ A tk listbox with drag'n'drop reordering of entries. """
  def __init__(self, master, **kw):
    kw['selectmode'] = tk.EXTENDED
    tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, kw)
    self.bind('<Button-1>', self.setCurrent)
    self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.shiftSelection)
    self.curIndex = None
  def setCurrent(self, event):
    self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.y)
  def shiftSelection(self, event):
    i = self.nearest(event.y)
    if i < self.curIndex:
      x = self.get(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i+1, x)
      self.curIndex = i
    elif i > self.curIndex:
      x = self.get(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i-1, x)
      self.curIndex = i

def update_ordering(*args):
  connect = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
  cursor = connect.cursor()
  field_ordering = [(order,fruit) for order,fruit in enumerate(ddlistbox.get(0, 'end'))]
  print(field_ordering)
  for field in field_ordering:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE columns SET 'ordering'="+str(field[0])+" WHERE fruit='"+field[1]+"';")
  connect.commit()
  connect.close()
  print(ddlistbox.curselection())

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical")
ddlistbox = Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
scrollbar.config(command=ddlistbox.yview)

def get_sqlite_report_fields():
  conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
  conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  fetch = cursor.execute("SELECT fruit FROM columns ORDER BY 'ordering';").fetchall()
  conn.close()
  return fetch

for fruit in get_sqlite_report_fields():
  ddlistbox.insert(0, fruit)
ddlistbox.config(width=30)
ddlistbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>' , func=update_ordering)
ddlistbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = tk.Button(root, text='Check', command=update_ordering)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is your code working? Does it raise an exception?

Comment: Are you missing a `commit` in your database transactions?

Comment: I'm only using `commit` when updating the ordering in the `update_ordering` function. All other times, I'm `SELECT`ing from the database, not updating.

Comment: This script always runs `make_sqlite_db_for_stackoverflow()` at the beginning. So it always reinitializes the database to the defaults. You probably want to check for the database and only initialize if it isn't there.

Comment: I know that. It was meant to help people recreate the scenario for creating the database. It can be commented out after running  the first time but the issue still remains. That's not the issue.

Comment: I just discovered that having the semicolon at the end of the `SELECT` query causes it to behave different than when there is no semicolon. I guessed this because the examples on the `sqlite3` docs don't use semicolons. There still seems to be an ordering issue for me, and you seem to have solved this yourself but I just thought I would let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Highly doubt anyone will answer my question so I'm posting my solution. It uses a drag-and-drop listbox to allow the user to arrange items in the listbox and saves their item ordering to a database for next time.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
root = tk.Tk()

class Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(tk.Listbox):
  """ A tk listbox with drag'n'drop reordering of entries. """
  def __init__(self, master, **kw):
    kw['selectmode'] = tk.EXTENDED
    tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, kw)
    self.bind('<Button-1>', self.setCurrent)
    self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.shiftSelection)
    self.curIndex = None
  def setCurrent(self, event):
    self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.y)
  def shiftSelection(self, event):
    i = self.nearest(event.y)
    if i < self.curIndex:
      x = self.get(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i+1, x)
      self.curIndex = i
    elif i > self.curIndex:
      x = self.get(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i-1, x)
      self.curIndex = i

def update_ordering(*args):
  connect = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
  cursor = connect.cursor()
  field_ordering = [(order,fruit) for order,fruit in enumerate(ddlistbox.get(0, 'end'))]
  print(field_ordering)
  for field in field_ordering:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE columns SET 'ordering'="+str(field[0])+" WHERE fruit='"+field[1]+"';")
  connect.commit()
  connect.close()
  print(ddlistbox.curselection())

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical")
ddlistbox = Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, activestyle='none')
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
scrollbar.config(command=ddlistbox.yview)

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
cursor = conn.cursor()
fetch = cursor.execute("SELECT fruit FROM columns ORDER BY ordering ASC").fetchall()
for field in fetch:
  ddlistbox.insert(tk.END, field)
ddlistbox.config(width=30)
ddlistbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = tk.Button(root, text='Check', command=update_ordering)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```